# Ways to set div width and height dynamically

Tags: css

Scenario 1:

Top header with 100% width and 50px height.

Left navigation bar with 200px width and dynamic height to fill the screen.

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.navBar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Scenario 2:

Top header with 100% width and 50px height.

Left navigation bar with 200px width and dynamic height to fill the screen.

A container on the right of the nav bar and under the header with dynamic width and height to fill the screen.

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
```

This will work, but I know it is not the best way to implement this. Some suggestions? Many thx!

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to accomplish, and what is the problem with this method?

Comment: @CalvinScherle Basically, there is no problem with this method. I just want suggestions or better ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **height:100%** to *html* and *body* tag.
Then use **calc()** css function for *height* and *width* properties to get result.

Refer my **snippet** for both the Scenarios . Its working.

```css
html, body{ height:100%;}
header{ width:100%; height:50px;background:#777;}
.nav{ height: calc( 100% - 50px ); width:200px; float:left; background:#888;}
.container{ color:#fff; float:left; width:calc( 100% - 200px ); height:calc( 100% - 50px ); background:#222;}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>  
<div class="nav">NAV</div>
<div class="container">Container</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeejvbu/8/) is you want.Just create layout like side menu and container as I created below check the fiddle too. This is an example for your scenario

```
html, body{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
body{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
}

header{
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    background:#f00;
}
aside{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    border-right:2px solid #ccc;
    left:0;
    width:20%;
    bottom:0;
    padding-top:50px;
    height:100%;
    backgroud:#f2f2f2;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
section.container{
    margin-left:20%;
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

HTML like

```
  <header></header>
    <aside>sidemenu</aside>
    <section class="container">
        container
    </section>
```